# Hash a timestamp with random distribution

Tags: java, hash

How can I take a timestamp generated by Date and create a String hash of it that is randomly distributed?

```
Date date = new Date().getTime();
```

So if I had timestamps that were sequential in order like this, they would have random string hashes (they can be any length but the shorter the better):

```
1659481151522
1659481151523
1659481151524
1659481151525
1659481151526
```

I want to make it clear I do not want the resulting hashes to be sequential. I tried doing this, but the hashes were sequential:

```
String.valueOf(timestamp).hashCode() // Not what I want.
```

The hash needs to be able to be calculated as fast as possible, so a longer hash that calculates faster is preferable to a short hash that takes longer to create.

Comment: What are you using the hashes for? Are you after cryptographic security, or well-distributed hashes to avoid degenerate data structure performance, or what?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I am seeking well-distributed hashes to avoid degenerate data structure performance. Security is not an issue.

Comment: If you're using something like `HashMap`, then sequential hashes will be fine.  Most hash-based structures should be fine with sequential hashes, in fact.  Why so picky?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I need a string so I can pass it to a de-duplicated system. I am not using a HashMap. Yes this is picky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Goals

You're looking for a way to:

- take a timestamp generated by Date and create a String hash of it that is randomly distributed
- the "random" nature isn't for cryptographic usage, or anything requiring true randomness
- instead, you're looking for a way to take two nearly identical numbers – 1659481151525 and 1659481151526, a difference of only 1 – and produce values for each which are no longer sequential
- the calculation needs to be "fast"

#### A possible solution

Disclaimer: all hashing has a non-zero risk of collisions. I suspect that many/most DIY hasing approaches have a higher risk of collisions.
You didn't discuss collisions in your question though, so I gather it isn't a priority.
I'll share this as an option to pursue (perhaps it's a starting point for something else like it), but I want to make it clear that while *I* didn't consider collisions, it doesn't necessarily follow that it's ok for *you* to also not consider collisions. Please consider collisions!

You gave the following example values as things to hash:

```
1659481151522
1659481151523
1659481151524
1659481151525
1659481151526
```

Here is a method which:

- takes the numeric long input, makes a copy to "temp"
- enters a loop that:

  - mods the last digit of "temp", always adding 1 (in case it's "0") multiplies it with the running total "result"
  - shifts bits in "temp" a little bit
  - repeats this process as long as "temp" is greater than 0

```
private static void modify(long original) {
    long result = 1L;
    long temp = original;
    do {
        result *= temp % 10 + 1;
        temp = temp >> 1;
    } while (temp > 0);
    System.out.println("original: " + original + " result: " + result);
}
```

Here's are those same five numbers, and the output from running the code:

```
modify(1659481151522L);
modify(1659481151523L);
modify(1659481151524L);
modify(1659481151525L);
modify(1659481151526L);

original: 1659481151522 result: -6525288372763164672
original: 1659481151523 result: -8700384497017552896
original: 1659481151524 result: 4267046283603279872
original: 1659481151525 result: -2258242089159884800
original: 1659481151526 result: -5562459257994215424
```

The "result" values are quite different from each other, even though the inputs were sequential.

I didn't benchmark anything, but the operations involved – bit shift, mod, addition, multiplication – are not complex.

---

#### UPDATE: MD5 example

Based on a comment below from *Micro*, here's an example showing how to calculate an MD5 hash for each long input value using [java.security.MessageDigest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html).

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md.update(String.valueOf(original).getBytes());
String md5 = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
```

Running the program again (also, editing the output to print MD5, too) would look like this:

```
original: 1659481151522 md5: a19327a6224dc0174cd323cc8e33cd11 result: -6525288372763164672
original: 1659481151523 md5: cfccb29f47f5f638c649e28f67a8f779 result: -8700384497017552896
original: 1659481151524 md5: b326c9ffaf7e0be85a729647d2242566 result: 4267046283603279872
original: 1659481151525 md5: bd0e15d7ee3056d7482cc379b69464fb result: -2258242089159884800
original: 1659481151526 md5: c28abd0668da70e8187eb6bbf0388c7c result: -5562459257994215424
```

---

#### Variation of original: Print hex value

If your goal is to include some letters in the mix – not just decimal values – you could take the "original" long value and simply format it differently. Here's an example doing that, also taking absolute value (avoid negative values). You might prefer one over the other, good to have options between a 16-char hexed long (ex: "5a8e7b33db890000") and a 32-char MD5 hash (ex: "a19327a6224dc0174cd323cc8e33cd11").

```
System.out.println("original: " + original +
        " original (hex): " + BigInteger.valueOf(Math.abs(result)).toString(16));

original: 1659481151522 original (hex): 5a8e7b33db890000
original: 1659481151523 original (hex): 78bdf99a7a0c0000
original: 1659481151524 original (hex): 3b3797fcb6530000
original: 1659481151525 original (hex): 1f56e33725360000
original: 1659481151526 original (hex): 4d31d33956540000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking it would use alphanumeric characters similar to an MD5 hash. Perhaps MD5 has is better for my purposes?

Comment: Sure, MD5 would work, and would create distributed values for sequential numeric inputs.

Comment: @Micro I just posted an edit to my answer including how you could calculate an MD5 hash for each long input.